# Adjust column width when exporting an Excel file

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I am trying to export data from Mysql to an excel file by using this code:

```
    $stories = Story::all();
    $header = 'Name' . "\t" . 'Email' . "\t" . 'Title' . "\t" . 'Created At' . "\t" . 'Story';
    $xsl = $header . "\n";
    foreach ($stories as $story)
    {
        $row = '';
        $row .= '"' . str_replace('"', '""', stripslashes($story->name )) . '"' . "\t";
        $row .= '"' . str_replace('"', '""', stripslashes($story->email)) . '"' . "\t";
        $row .= '"' . str_replace('"', '""', stripslashes($story->title)) . '"' . "\t";
        $row .= '"' . str_replace('"', '""', stripslashes($story->created_at)) . '"' . "\t";
        $row .= '"' . str_replace('"', '""', stripslashes($story->story)) . '"' . "\t";

        $xsl .= trim($row) . "\n";
    }

    $xsl = str_replace("\\t", "", $xsl);

    return Response::make($xsl)->header('Content-type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel')->header('Content-disposition', "attachment;filename=Stories [as of].xls");
```

The issue is how is it possible to give the columns auto width?

Comment: What you're generating looks like a TSV file (tab-separated values) to me. This format has no support for formatting options like auto-width. If you need to define the format in which Excel shows the data, you need to output a different format, e.g. Excel's own Excel XML stuff (.xlsx), which is much more complex, so maybe look for a library that can help you with that.

Comment: @TillHelge Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a huge library to export excel. You can build **almost genuine** excel file just by using the proper `meta` in a html file.

You will have to include in your header something like this:

```
<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<xml>
    <x:ExcelWorkbook>
        <x:ExcelWorksheets>
            <x:ExcelWorksheet>
                <x:Name>Sheet 1</x:Name>
                <x:WorksheetOptions>
                    <x:Print>
                        <x:ValidPrinterInfo/>
                    </x:Print>
                </x:WorksheetOptions>
            </x:ExcelWorksheet>
        </x:ExcelWorksheets>
    </x:ExcelWorkbook>
</xml>
<![endif]-->
...
```

The full code snipped I'm actually using is below. Based on what it's written there, it is likely this code will not work on earlier versions of MS Office. Please note that this is a Blade view.

```html
<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <xml>
        <x:ExcelWorkbook>
            <x:ExcelWorksheets>
                <x:ExcelWorksheet>
                    <x:Name>Sheet 1</x:Name>
                    <x:WorksheetOptions>
                        <x:Print>
                            <x:ValidPrinterInfo/>
                        </x:Print>
                    </x:WorksheetOptions>
                </x:ExcelWorksheet>
            </x:ExcelWorksheets>
        </x:ExcelWorkbook>
    </xml>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<table>
    @if(!empty($thead))
        <thead>
        {!! $thead !!}
        </thead>
    @endif
    @if(!empty($tbody))
        <tbody>
        {!! $tbody !!}
        </tbody>
    @endif
    @if(!empty($tfoot))
        <tfoot>
        {!! $tfoot !!}
        </tfoot>
    @endif
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The trick here is you can take advantages of various features like columns and rows merging (with `colspan` and `rowspan`) and many more (it's working with alignment classes like `text-center` and `text-right`).

You can force downloading the file with a code in your controller like that:

```
$fileName = "export.xls";

$data = View::make('export.excel.table', [
    'thead' => $thead,
    'tbody' => $tbody,
    'tfoot' => $tfoot,
]);

return Response::make($data, 200, [
    'Content-type'        => 'application/excel',
    'Content-Type'        => 'application/excel',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=' . $fileName
]);
```

Hope that helps.